# OpenApi -API with X-WWW-FORM-URLEncoded as requestBody

Tags: java, openapi, openapi-generator

I am using openapi 3.0.3 and I am trying to write an API which accepts data in the form of
'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' by api specification looks something like this:

```
/path/to/api/v1/testApi:
    post:
      tags:
        - Extract data
      operationId: "testApi"   
    requestBody:
     content:
       application/x-www-form-urlencoded:
         schema:
          type: object
          properties:
            effectiveDate:
              type: string
     required: true
```

using the above specification when an api is generated automatically, the request is accepted by the api as @RequestParam.

```
ResponseEntity<String> testAPi(
        @Parameter(name = "effectiveDate", description = "") @Valid @RequestParam(value = "effectiveDate", required = false) String effectiveDate
    ) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED);

    }
```

Is there a possibility to make it accept @RequestBody instead of @RequestParam with the same x-www-form-urlencoded data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to force an open-api POST requestBody with application/x-www-form-urlencoded content to generate a Java Controller method that accepts a  @RequestBody instead of @RequestParam.

The reason is that the *The Servlet API requires ServletRequest.getParameter() methods to support **form field** access only for **HTTP POST***.- from [spring-framework/docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/6.0.x/reference/html/web.html#filters-http-put)

Also [ServletRequest.html#getParameter(java.lang.String)](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter(java.lang.String))

Comment: Hi. I have a problem. I use the same configuration that @ananya, but  I need read the form content and requestparam only read get params and not the body content sent post content send by form.